# Thickness of pattern fill in Gnuplot

Tags: gnuplot

I am using Gnuplot and I wish to fill the area between two curves with transparent hatched pattern.

I define fill style with:

> set style fill transparent pattern 1

and I plot it as:

> plot "Data..." using 4:1:2 with filledcurves lc rgb 'black'

However, the resulting hatched pattern has extremely thick lines. I want to adjust thickness of pattern lines, density of lines etc.

I cannot believe I could not find anyone asking the same thing?

Comment: Please give a full working, but minimal example.  Especially including terminal and terminal options, and your gnuplot version

Comment: From `help fillstyle`: "The kind and number of available fill patterns
 depend on the terminal driver". Maybe try a different terminal? If you just type `test` you will see the available patterns.

Comment: @nevermind There are only very limited fill patterns. About a year later I asked about something similar, i.e. hatch patterns. But the answer is rather complicated see: https://stackoverflow.com/q/53547501/7295599