# Hatching (Pattern fill) in Gnuplot

Tags: gnuplot

In the attached image I want to have hatched lines in the entire region  to the left the dashed line i.e. in the region before x = -4. How can this be done?

[image]

Comment: Hatch patterns in gnuplot are limited. Just in case you are interested in hatching arbitrary areas with more flexible hatch patterns, here is a (complicated) solution: https://stackoverflow.com/a/63471784/7295599

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
set object 1 rectangle from graph 0,0 to first -4, graph 1
set object 1 fillstyle pattern 1 fillcolor "cyan"
set xrange [-5:5]
set grid x y
plot sin(x)
```

[image]